# How To SUM, GROUP and SPLIT data in MYSQL Database Based on Dates

Tags: mysql, sql

Table: Accounting

```
date_due        date_paid         amount_due     amount_paid    category_type
2012-08-12      2012-08-12        500            450            Income
2012-08-13      2012-08-17        200            300            Expense
2012-09-15      2012-09-13        300            300            Income
2012-09-17      2012-09-16        100            100            Income
```

How do I Generate a Table Like:

```
date_paid       IncomeAmountPaid               ExpenseAmountPaid
2012-08         TOTAL INCOME IN AUGUST         TOTAL EXPENSE IN AUGUST
2012-09         TOTAL INCOME IN SEPT.          TOTAL EXPENSE IN SEPTEMBER
```

Comment: would be able to help you more if you said what you wanted to sum, group and split

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following, which implements a `CASE` statement and a `GROUP BY`:

```
select date_format(date_paid, '%Y-%m') date_paid,
  sum(case when category_type = 'Income' then amount_paid end) IncomePaid,
  sum(case when category_type = 'Expense' then amount_paid end) ExpensePaid
from accounting 
group by date_format(date_paid, '%Y-%m')
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01255/2)

Answer (score 0):

**How to GROUP**

```
SELECT column_name, aggregate_function(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name operator value
GROUP BY column_name
```

**How to SUM**

```
SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM table_name
```

**How to SPLIT**

create a split function

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, '');
```

then use the function

```
SELECT SPLIT_STR(string, delimiter, position)
```

Answer (score 0):

u can try this,

```
 select Year(date_paid), Month(date_paid),
  sum(case when category_type = 'Income' then amount_paid end) IncomeAmountPaid,
  sum(case when category_type = 'Expense' then amount_paid end) ExpenseAmountPaid
 group by Year(date_paid), Month(date_paid)
```